# Raspberry Pi won’t connect to serial port

Tags: raspbian

Hi I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B connected to an official Raspberry Pi 7” touchscreen. I wanted to use it on my OpenBuilds OX CNC with a Spark Concepts xPro3 controller. When I use the CNC with my MacBook Pro it connects to the controller port every time, but try as I may it will not connect to the Pi. The connection is via a USB cable.
I’m a noob and reading loads about how to connect and all I could find was to enter the command lusb. I get the following:-

```
Bus 001 Device 005 ID 0403:6025 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd Bridge(I2C/SPI/UART/FIFO)
Bus 001 Device 004 ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 001 Device 003 ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9515 Fast Ethernet Adaptor
Bus 001 Device 002 ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am using Universal Gcode Sender which is an open source Java programme and I’m given the choice of 2 ports to connect to. ttyUSB0 and ttyAM0. Neither works, as said it works perfectly on my MacBook. Can anyone please help me before I consign the Pi to the bin.

Comment: Hi @Ken, Welcome and Nice to meet you.  Ah, let me see. (1) You have the following 3 things; (a) Mac Book Pro, (b) CNC xPro3 controller, (c) Rpi3B. (2) Mac Book Pro running UGS (Universal Gode Sender) can connect to xPro3 without any problem. (3) Now the PROBLEM: Rpi running UGS cannot connect to exPro3, either using Rpi's USB to TTL cable, or on board UART (TxD, RxD pins). Please confirm if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: Just now I made a casual google search and found xPro3 talks to Arduino but no mention about Rpi.  Can you give me pointer to user guide on xPro3 to Rpi3B hooking up?

Comment: Unplug your CNC device then plug it back in. The kernel messages seen with a `dmesg` command should tell you which `/dev/ttyXXX` device is instantiated when your USB CNC device is connected. You may find that there's no kernel driver for it. You may need to contact the machine's maker to find whether they have a custom made driver and whether that is supported on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Hi UGS is a cross platform JAVA . I plug a USB 2.0 Type A into the Pi and a USB 2.0 Type B plug into the CNC xPro3 controller. I’m assuming the Serial thing is built into the controller. On the OpenBuilds website there are a number of people using Raspberry Pi’s with the xPro controller so I’m assuming it to be compatible. I unplugged the controller as suggested and the reconnected it. I got FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0, still no joy. I then downloaded and reinstalled the Raspbian operating system, restarted and it now all appears to work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi @Ken, Many thanks for your pointer to OpenBuilds.  I found their Rpi projects are still experimental and unofficial.  So I would stall for now, and perhaps come back some time later to catch up.  Cheers. (1) https://github.com/OpenBuilds/OpenBuilds-CONTROL/wiki
(2) https://github.com/OpenBuilds/OpenBuilds-CONTROL/wiki/Run-on-a-Raspberry-Pi-(No-Compile-Method)
(3) https://github.com/OpenBuilds/OpenBuilds-CONTROL/wiki/Compiling-on-Raspberry-Pi-%5Bunofficial%5D